# Stored procedure updating all the values of a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to update table event_alerts with either Yes/No.

But, when this stored procedure is being called, all the values of the column(server_match) are being updated.

I need only the row which is affected to be updated. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
create procedure [dbo].[servermatch_apacservers]
as
update event_alerts 
set event_alerts.server_match = (case when apac_servers.List_of_servers is null then 'NO' else 'YES' end)
from event_alerts
left join apac_servers on apac_servers.List_of_servers = event_alerts.server_name;
```

Comment: "I need only the row which is affected"; which is that row? You have no `where` clause, so naturally all rows will be updated.

Comment: yes even i had that doubt on where clause, can you help on framing the where clause condition

Comment: If you can explain the condition in words, I may be able to help putting it in a `where`

Comment: There are two tables i.e, events_alerts and apac_servers, each time a new value gets updated in event_alerts. Then the stored procedure is called to check if the same value is found in apac_servers. if found, the column server_match gets updated with yes, or else no.

Comment: Sounds like something you should do in a trigger, where you know which rows are affected. This procedure has no way of knowing which row was updated

Comment: You need to provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You need an argument to specify WHAT row gets updated.  Let me assume that you have a `server_name` column to identify the server:

```
create procedure [dbo].[servermatch_apacservers] (
    @server_name varchar(255)
) as begin

    update event_alerts 
        set server_match = (case when exists (select 1
                                              from apac_servers a
                                              where a.List_of_servers =  event_alerts.server_name
                                             )
                                 then 'YES' else 'NO'
                            end)
        where server_name = @server_name;
END;
```

That said, this logic can easily be run as a query -- and encapsulated as a view.  There is no need to try to keep this up-to-date in the table, under most circumstances.

You might want to put it in a trigger.  However, that requires a trigger for `insert`s, `update`s, and `delete`s.